# Is this a good architecture for a recursive MongoDB archiver written in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, stream, database

I am currently challenged with archiving data on a MongoDB server that has been running for over a year, accumulating nearly 100GB of data (many collections having 10+ million documents). Much to my disappointment, the data model was designed in a way very similar to what you would expect to see in a relational database; a collection for each Model and foreign keys associating records to each other. For example:

```
// Collection: conversations (~1M documents)
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  last_read_at: new Date,
}

// Collection: messages (~100M documents, 0-200k per conversation)
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  conversation: ObjectId(),
}

// Collection: likes (~50M documents, 0-1k per message)
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  message: ObjectId(),
}
```

If I was faced with a traditional RDBMS I could quite easily use `JOIN` to find and destroy all of the relevant `chapters` and `pages`, archive them, then `DELETE` them. Unfortunately I'm not so lucky.

My current approach is this:

- Query for all books that haven't been read in `n` days and pipe results to **Archive Strategy**
- **Archive Strategy** - In parallel:

  - Archive the documents to a file using `pipe()` from the `Cursor`
  - Document by document, query other collections that reference document, pipe results into new **Archive Strategy** stream

What we end up with is a dependency tree where the root is the collection we actually want to archive, and each level in the tree is a stream for archiving its dependencies. Given our dataset and model complexity this has turned out to be unbearably slow. I guess I have two questions:

1. Can I avoid the n+1 queries somehow, or is this simply a constraint of MongoDB since I can't join? My next idea here is to batch dependency the queries in groups using `$in`
2. Are streams the most effective way to handle a workload like this?

Comment: Pretty broad question, but be sure to use `$in` to query for all docs that reference a set of ref ids rather than doing it one by one.

Comment: @JohnnyHK thanks for the response. Using `$in` is what I was alluding to in question 1–I'll clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully re-architected the program producing speed gains of over 100X by making the following changes:

- Rather than producing a tree of streams, I broke up each branch into individual jobs which I placed into a queue. This necessitated saving intermediate data (`_id`s and other keys needed to crawl) temporarily to disk but that turned out to have no impact on speed since each branch was bottlenecked elsewhere. This allowed each branch of the crawl run at its own pace without slowing down faster branches. The tree design ended up having way too much contention to work.
- I consumed the above mentioned queue in `n` worker processes using cluster the module where `n` was the number of CPU cores I had.
- When consuming the `_id`s from disk, I batched them into groups of 1000 to minimize the number of queries I had to perform.

Using the above methods I was able to archive over 100M documents in about three hours with no noticeable impact on user experience. The program is now CPU bound but runs fast enough that I won't be digging deeper.